# initialising a variable inside try block, a workaround?

Tags: java, initialization, try-catch

I have a `try-catch` block; inside `try`, I read variable `N` from console and initialize an `Array[N]`. I need to use `Array` later. If I use it outside `try` block, I get an error

`java variable may not have been initialized`.

I understand it, but what should I do, write the whole program inside `try` block, really? Readability of such program is worse and I use `try` on the code where is no `exceptions` are possible. Is there a workaround? I tried a `boolean` variable which checks was there an exception and use it later in a `if` statement - no results.

Comment: Just declare the array before the try block or use it in the block.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Object[] yourArray = null;
try {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Exceptions are possible everywhere, even at lines which do not call any methods.

Your problem is *yet another* example of the failure that Java's *checked exceptions* are, especially to beginners: they seem to be forcing you to write the try-catch, and even misguiding you into thinking these are the only exceptions that may arise.

The try-catch block must cover the precise area of code which must be executed conditional on everything above each line having completed normally, and which shares the same mode of error handling. This has absolutely nothing to do with checked/unchecked exceptions.

Therefore, without knowing precisely what your requirements are, you can't be given specific advice on where to put try and catch.

Answer (score 1):

The variables declared in a block will be accessible in that block only.
You can define your array outside try block and then use in the try block

```
String [] arr = null;
try{
  // assign value here
 }catch(Exception e){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically have two options:

1. write your code inside the `try catch` block as you suggest
2. initialize your array to `null` outside the `try catch` block and later check that your array is not `null` and has well been initialized

Answer (score 0):

you should declare the variable outside if the try...catch... clause

```
Integer n = null;
try{
    some code goes here
    .
    .
    .
catch(Exception e){
}
```

remember to think about variable scope.
a variable or object declared inside a try catch clause or a method or any other that goes inside {}  is not visible to other parts of the class

hope this was helpful

Comment: You can't put null into int. You need to use an Integer.

Answer (score 0):

if you declare a variable in try block, (for that matter in any block) it will be local to that particular block, the life time of the variable expires after the execution of the block. Therefore, you cannot access any variable declared in a block, outside it.