# Java try block code does not execute

Tags: java, exception, applet, try-catch

I do not understand why the code in this try block does not execute. I get a compilation error that says when I use these variables after the try block, they may not be initialized.

```
double star, planet, posLife, actLife, intelLife, comm, length;

try{
    star = Double.parseDouble(factor.elementAt(0).getText());    
    planet = Double.parseDouble(factor.elementAt(1).getText());
    posLife = Double.parseDouble(factor.elementAt(2).getText());
    actLife = Double.parseDouble(factor.elementAt(3).getText());
    intelLife = Double.parseDouble(factor.elementAt(4).getText());
    comm = Double.parseDouble(factor.elementAt(5).getText());
    length = Double.parseDouble(factor.elementAt(6).getText());
} catch(NumberFormatException E){ 
    System.err.println("NumberFormatException");
}
```

Comment: Scope of local variables is limited by `{` and `}` braces. This means you will not have access to variables declared inside `try` block in rest of code (like in `catch` or after `try`. But judging by error you mentioned it may seem that you shadowed variables declared before `try` by redeclaring new variables with same names. In that case simply remove type like change `double star = ...` to ` star = ...` to avoid redeclaring.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399669/initialising-a-variable-inside-try-block-a-workaround

Comment: Actually, I had the variables declared outside the block before. I still had the same problem, because no variable assignments were being made within the try block. I appreciate your help, but the situation remains largely unchanged.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. I had tried declaring the variables outside of the try block, but strangely I have to also initialize the variables outside of the try block to allow the variables to take assignments within the try block. Weird...

Answer (score 5):

First, the variables you define in the try block should not be visible outside the try block ; so I believe you must have another `double star;` etc. before the try.

Now, I'll assume your code is more like the following, because the error you spoke of could not occur with the code you gave us:

```
double a;
try {
    a = Double.parseDouble(/* blah */);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.err.println("NumberFormatException");
}
```

Here, after the execution of this block of code, `a` may perfectly well be uninitialized. Indeed, if any error occured in `Double.parseDouble`, the assignment to `a` would be skipped to jump to the catch block, which does not return.

Thus, after the above block of code, `a` may be uninitialized, hence the error message.

To fix it, you should remove the types before the variables inside the `try` block, and either provide a default value in case it's impossible to parse the double, or, if the exception cannot be recovered from in *this scope*, do not catch it in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

You should assign a default value to the doubles before trying to access them, I've given mine a value of `-1`

You must declare the vars you're using in the try-catch before the try block if you need to used them after the try-catch block.

Here is an example of this.

```
//Some default value
double star = -1;

try {
    star = 0;
} catch(NumberFormatException E){ 
    System.err.println("NumberFormatException");
}

//You can use this now.
System.out.println(star);
```

Comment: Oops, sorry, I downvoted you based on the fact that the variables are *not* declared in the `try` block, and the edit history showed that they weren't declared in the `try` block in the original version of the question, either--but I just noticed that you probably wrote this answer in response to the *second* version of the question, in which the variables *are* declared in the `try` block. My bad.

Comment: Technically my code sample is correct, you need to assign the double's to an initial value, see my other answer. Remove that down vote if at-all possible. :-)

Comment: I realize that, which is why I apologized. (I did the same thing for Steve Kuo's answer, but since his still ignores the underlying problem, I didn't bother apologizing.) My vote is locked in unless your answer is edited--which, by the way, it *should* be, because rather than having two answers, you should simply edit this one to reflect updates to the original question.

Comment: I've updated this to reflect the changes. I'll edit my answer next time instead of creating a new one, makes sense. Thanks Kyle.

Comment: No problem. Ideally you should also delete your other answer; there are very few instances when posting multiple answers on the same question are encouraged. (And in fact I think it's somewhat debated whether this is *ever* desirable.)

Comment: I can see instances where more then one answer is helpful, this is _not_ one of those times though, so I've deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

The scope of `star`, `planet`, etc are limited to the try block. You'll need to declare them outside and before the try block.

```
double star = null;
try {
  star = Double.parseDouble(...
} catch(NumberFormatException e) {
  ...
}

System.out.println(star);
```

Comment: Here you would get the error the OP is mention. Because if the parsing fails star is not initialized.

Comment: Fixed, star defaults to null

Comment: Any primitive data type can **never** be `null`.

Answer (score 1):

You mention that you've already figured it out: "strangely I have to also initialize the variables outside of the try block..."

That's not "strange". Think about all possible paths this code can take at runtime, *including* the exceptional one. If you `catch` an exception, what happens? The program continues, but *none of the code in the `try` block is guaranteed to have been executed*. So you might have uninitialized variables. And by "might" I mean "definitely will," because the fact that an exception occurs at all means that *something* in the `try` block didn't finish executing, so at a minimum, you know that the last statement that happens in the block did *not* go to completion--which means that `length` was *never assigned to*.

And therefore, if an exception occurs, you will leave the `try` block with `length` (and probably others, possibly all of your `double`s) uninitialized.

Note also that although your question asks why the code in the `try` block "doesn't execute", the error you're seeing is a *compile* error, stating that the variables *may* not be initialized. If the compiler cannot *ensure* that a variable will be initialized, it throws this error--and if your initialization code is in any sort of conditionally-executed block (such as an `if` statement or, as in this case, a `try` block), then of course the compiler can't ensure that the block will always be executed, so it can't guarantee that the variables will be initialized!